# GUI builder Python for Linux and OSX

Tags: python

I just want something that is easiest to use for building a relatively simple GUI that
ports easily to OSX and Ubuntu Linux.

More than anything, I just want to get cracking on the App rather than getting caught up in
making something super polished, etc.

GLADE comes up a lot but doesn't strike me as the easiest, though, if someone suggests otherwise I'm open.

Again, main criteria is ease of use and portability to OSX and Linux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There a quite a few options that you have:

PyQt is one : here is an intro : http://www.rkblog.rk.edu.pl/w/p/introduction-pyqt4/

PyGTK http://pygtk.org/ heard some good reviews for it but have not played with it.

wxPython is another : http://wxpython.org/what.php

I would suggest the wxPython but its totally up to you.

Have a look at their documentation and then pick.

Enjoy